# Who can exclude Same origin policy?

Tags: jquery, ajax, same-origin-policy

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/rwrtx/4/). Why

```
$.ajax({
    type : "get",
    url : "http://www.facebook.com",        
    success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
     }
});
```

works and

```
$.ajax({
    type : "get",
    url : "http://www.google.com",        
    success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
     }
});
```

throw the famous `XMLHttpRequest cannot load` Same origin policy exception on the browser console!

Why? I guess it depends by the browser?

Comment: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work -- it just doesn't produce an error.

Comment: the request to facebook does not reach the success callback and does not get a response. The request seems to have been canceled before it could reach the same origin error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`http://www.facebook.com` sends a `301 Moved Permanently` response, which redirects to `https://www.facebook.com`.

It appears that the redirect causes the request to fail more quietly than an outright cross-domain failure. However, both requests *do* fail.

**EDIT**

According to the [W3C Ajax specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#infrastructure-for-the-send%28%29-method):

> **If the response has an HTTP status code of 301, 302, 303, 307, or 308** ...
>
> 1. Set the request URL to the URL conveyed by the Location header.
> 2. If the source origin and the origin of request URL are same origin transparently follow the redirect while observing the same-origin request event rules.
> 3. Otherwise, follow the cross-origin request steps and terminate the steps for this algorithm.

The text "transparently follow the redirect" means that Ajax should treat the target of 301 redirects as the original target. However, when performing a redirect, the same-origin policy is re-checked against the new target origin.

The target domain must also have the same origin as the requesting script, or it must respond with CORS headers that allow access by the requesting origin.

Comment: jQuery does not follow any redirects in ajax calls (at least not for the last time where i checked). Probably the cross domain policy, if browser support CORS, would only be violated if the final url does not allow the access. (But i need to check the specs, to be sure about this)

Comment: Can you be more specific about "fail more quietly"?

Comment: @t.niese Ajax redirects are perfectly valid; see my edit with a citation from the W3C spec.

Answer (score 1):

It is up to the server (facebook, google, etc) to allow their content to be loaded across domains. This is called Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. To enable CORS on your server, provide this header in your response: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

You cannot change the behavior of a server you do not own.

Comment: Well, but allowing all domains as origin ('*') is a bad idea, this completely disables SOP.

Comment: What makes you call it a blatantly bad idea? In cases such as API calls using bearer tokens, this is a reasonable setting to have. 
Even for those apps that support cookies based authentication, merely having this setting doesnt seem like a bad idea to me. Do you have a scenario in mind? @Tali